# Trying to copy rows from one sheet if it has the entered date

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy rows from one sheet to another if they have dates that match. I've used this method before and it worked fine. I can't work out where I'm going wrong here for the life of me.

```
Public Sub dayreport()
    Dim enteredday As Variant
    Dim clockinday As Variant
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim yreport As Integer
    Dim yrow As Integer
    Dim daystring As String
    Dim datecheck As Boolean
    'Collect the entered date
    enteredday = CVar(Sheets("Process").Cells(3, 3)) 'get the datestring out of the date cell
    'Only progress if a date is entered
    If IsDate(enteredday) = True Then
        datecheck = True    'a usable date has been entered
    Else
        datecheck = False
        MsgBox "Entered date must be a real date of the format dd/mm/yyyy"
    End If
    If datecheck = True Then
        'Delete the day report if it already exists
        Call Delete_Sheet("Day Report")
        'create a new sheet
        Worksheets.Add.name = "Day Report"

        y = 7
        yreport = 7
        yrow = 7
        'While there is data in any of the cells of the investigated row, loop
        Do While Sheets("Process").Cells(y, 1) <> "" _
                    Or Sheets("Process").Cells(y, 2) <> "" _
                    Or Sheets("Process").Cells(y, 3) <> "" _
                    Or Sheets("Process").Cells(y, 4) <> "" _
                    Or Sheets("Process").Cells(y, 5) <> "" _
                    Or Sheets("Process").Cells(y, 6) <> "" _
                    Or Sheets("Process").Cells(y, 7) <> "" _
                    Or Sheets("Process").Cells(y, 8) <> "" _

            'breakdown entered date
            year = CInt(Right(enteredday, 4))   'take the year component from the date and convert it to an integer
            month = CInt(Mid(enteredday, 4, 2))     'take the month component from the date and convert it to an integer
            day = CInt(Left(enteredday, 2))     'take the day component from the date and convert it to an integer
            enteredday = DateSerial(year, month, day)

            'Breakdown investigated date
            clockinday = CVar(Sheets("Process").Cells(y, 2)) 'get the datestring out of the date cell
            sheetyear = CInt(Right(clockinday, 4))
            sheetmonth = CInt(Mid(clockinday, 4, 2))
            sheetday = CInt(Left(clockinday, 2))
            clockinday = DateSerial(sheetyear, sheetmonth, sheetday)

            'copy the row pairs into the day report sheet if the entered date matches the date in the row
            If enteredday = clockinday Then



                For i = 1 To 9

                    Sheets(“Day Report”).Cells(yreport, i) = Sheets(“Process”).Cells(y, i)
                    Sheets(“Day Report”).Cells(yreport + 1, i) = Sheets(“Process”).Cells(y + 1, i)
                    yreport = yreport + 2
                Next i
            End If
            yrow = yrow + 2
            y = y + 2
        Loop

    End If

End Sub
```

Instead of the for-loop copying dates, I also tried,

```
Worksheets("Process").Range(CVar("A" & yrow & ":" & "I" & yrow + 1)).Copy Worksheets(“Day Report”).Range(CVar("A" & yreport & ":" & "I" & yreport + 1))
```

It seems as though it is not able to see my Process sheet, yet it was populated by another sub which runs perfectly

Comment: Why break up the date into pieces? Why not just look for an exact match of `mm/dd/yyyy` etc.?

Comment: ...or cast it to a `Date` and use that?

Comment: The date is broken up to divvy out information later on so I can just call the month etc. I was trying to make this easier for me as I go along

Comment: @S.Deans I think you're making it harder - if you have a date in `mm/dd/yyyy` you can always call the month from that by doing `Month(mm/dd/yyyy)`, or the day by `Day(mm/dd/yyyy)` etc...

Comment: You're also using invalid quotation marks in your lines `Sheets(“Day Report”).Cells(yreport, i) = Sheets(“Process”).Cells(y, i)` and `Sheets(“Day Report”).Cells(yreport + 1, i) = Sheets(“Process”).Cells(y + 1, i)` - change those to normal `"`.

Comment: There is a time component associated to the date too. I was trying to get the difference in time across days to the second. I used DateSerial in the sub which populated the Process sheet, but couldnt find anything which included the time too, so I just broke it up and handled it manually

Comment: That was it! the quotation marks! Thank you!

I have no idea why my keyboard entered those kinds of quotation marks, but I copied yours in and that's it now (buggily) copying things over